# Do features have to be float numbers for multiclass-classification by Decision Tree?

Tags: python, pandas, decision-tree, multiclass-classification, named-entity-recognition

```
X_train

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | bias | word.lower | word[-3:] | word.isupper | word.isdigit |  POS  |  BOS  |  EOS  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  |  1.0 | headache,  |      HE,  |         True |        False |   NNP |  True | False |
1  |  1.0 |    mostly  |      tly  |        False |        False |   NNP | False | False |
2  |  1.0 |       but  |      BUT  |         True |        False |   NNP | False | False |
...
...
...

y_train

------------
   |  OBI  |
------------
0  | B-ADR |
1  | O     |
2  | O     |
...
...
...
```

I'm trying to do Name Entity Recognition (**NER**) with **Decision Tree**. My features dataframe and label dataframe look like the above. When I run the following code, it returns `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'headache,'`. Are my data in the proper form (I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decision-tree-classification-python))? Do features have to be **float numbers** for multiclass-classification by Decision Tree? If so, how should I proceed the OBI labeling, given that most token features, if not all, are either string or Boolean?

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

DT = DecisionTreeClassifier()
DT.fit(X_train, y_train)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-aa02be64ac27> in <module>
      1 DT = DecisionTreeClassifier()
----> 2 DT.fit(X_train, y_train)

d:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    888         """
    889 
--> 890         super().fit(
    891             X, y,
    892             sample_weight=sample_weight,

d:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    154             check_X_params = dict(dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    155             check_y_params = dict(ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
--> 156             X, y = self._validate_data(X, y,
    157                                        validate_separately=(check_X_params,
    158                                                             check_y_params))

d:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    427                 # :(
    428                 check_X_params, check_y_params = validate_separately
--> 429                 X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)
    430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    431             else:

d:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

d:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    596                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    597                 else:
--> 598                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    599             except ComplexWarning:
    600                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

d:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'headache,'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they need to be **numeric** (not necessarily float). So if you have 4 distinct text labels in a column then you need to convert this to 4 numbers. To do this, use sklearn's labelencoder. If your data is in a pandas dataframe `df`,

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from collections import defaultdict

# select text columns
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

# this is a way to apply label_encoder to all category cols at once, returning a label encoder per categorical column, in a dict d 
d = defaultdict(preprocessing.LabelEncoder)

 # transform all text columns to numbers
df[cat_cols] = df[cat_cols].apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x.astype(str)))
```

Once you have converted all columns to numbers, you may also wish to ["one-hot"](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) encode. Do this for categorical and boolean columns (here I've shown it for your categorical columns only).

```
# you should probably also one-hot the categorical columns
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cat_cols)
```

You can retrieve the names of the values from the label encoder afterwards using the dict `d` of label encoders.

```
d[col_name].inverse_transform(value)
```

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/vickdata/four-feature-types-and-how-to-transform-them-for-machine-learning-8693e1c24e80) is particularly useful for understanding these concepts.

Comment: Thank you! I add `from collections import defaultdict` and it works perfectly well!

Comment: Whoops! I've added this in.